# Can not register reuseIdentifier for collectionView, why?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I get error: **does not have a member named 'registerClass'**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.collectionView.registerClass(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "title")
    self.collectionView.registerClass(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "content")
}
```

Why, what is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unwrap the conditional for the collection view (the error message you get when you leave out the "!" is confusing -- I don't know why it mentions numberOfItemsInSection),

```
self.collectionView!.registerClass(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "title")
```